# Where is System.CoreEx.dll for Rx.NET

Tags: c#, system.reactive

This might seem like a silly question, but I downloaded the Reactive Extensions for .NET from here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896.aspx

This simple example is giving me a build error:

```
var test = new[] { 1, 2, 4, 5 };
test.ToObservable().Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);
```

The compiler says:

> Error 2   The type
>   'System.Concurrency.IScheduler' is
>   defined in an assembly that is not
>   referenced. You must add a reference
>   to assembly 'System.CoreEx,
>   Version=1.0.2856.104, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. C:\dev\test\RxTests.cs  67  13  Test

System.CoreEx is not on the same list of assemblies as System.Reactive was ... any clues?

Comment: It is shown at 1:07 in this introductory video: http://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/j.van.gogh/writing-your-first-rx-application

Comment: Thanks Hans. I hardly imagine that a passing mention in an introductory video is good documentation. At least search engines can now find this SO post for future reactive programmers :-)

Comment: Also just found out, that a lot of the linq-ish Rx code also doesn't build without `using System.Reactive.Linq;` on the top!

Comment: For people who stumble across this thread:  They have also moved the LINQ extension methods for `IObservable<T>` from `System.Linq` to `System.Reactive.Linq`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the latest version of Rx, System.CoreEx.dll has been removed and the contents merged with System.Reactive.dll.  See the release notes for other changes.

Answer (score 3):

It's part of the reactive package (that's the same version number as System.Reactive).

I'm surprised it's not in the .NET reference list; you can find it in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Cloud Programmability\Reactive Extensions, or it ought to be in the GAC too.

Comment: cloud programmability? yep, that was it ... I just didn't think to look in that folder :-) but yeah, it's not on the ref list, nor is it in the GAC. Thanks!

Comment: Mine was in Program Files (x86) by the way

Answer (score 1):

I had the same. Searched my system drive, but no system.coreEx.dll. Then tried to install it via VS-extention NuGet. That did the job for me.

Comment: In the latest version of Rx, System.CoreEx.dll has been removed and consolidated into System.Reactive.dll.  I think the NuGet package is probably an older version.

Answer (score 1):

use Manage NuGet Package and search and install System.Reactive.
obtain the path to System.Reactive.dll
And there you will find

the System.CoreEx.dll and System.Interactive.dll
which now you can reference as well.